# T-SQL Use the IF Update(fieldname) in a update trigger dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to do something like this in an update(before) trigger

```
declare
   @myfield varchar(20)

set @myfield = 'currency'

if update(@myfield) ...do something
```

If works if I do like this `...if update([currency])`

//MarieKH

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
declare @myfield sysname

set @myfield = 'currency'

if update(@myfield) ...do something
```

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191240(v=sql.105)) for details about the sysname data type.